# How to return average value - Azure Cognitive search or Semantic search query

Tags: azure, search, azure-cognitive-search, azure-data-lake-gen2

How to use semantic search(or querytype=simple) and return average of a field.
For example, I have a sample [csv file](https://github.com/IBM/employee-attrition-aif360/blob/master/data/emp_attrition.csv) with tabular data in my datalake blob container
I want to use azure semantic search and find the average age of employees
I generated the semantic search indexer,indexes etc along with azure Datalake as DataSource where I uploaded my CSV file.Now I want to send semantic search query to the API and get meaningful insights as API response

Here are some of the sample queries I tried(pasted below).How to properly sent JSON parameters to API and return average age. (Similar to SQL query SELECT AVG(age) FROM EMPLOYEES)

Is there a way I can fetch insights(in JSON format) from the table of records in my CSV file/DataLake.How can I generate insights and fetch those insights through my semantic search API call?

Is there anything wrong with my query I am sending to the API? How can I get more insights in JSON format.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Semantic search will only return verbatim statements from your index. It cannot calculate the average from tabular data. See documentation for [Returning a semantic answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/semantic-answers?tabs=semanticConfiguration#what-is-a-semantic-answer):

> A semantic answer is a substructure of a semantic query response. It
> consists of one or more verbatim passages from a search document,
> formulated as an answer to a query that looks like a question. To
> return an answer, **phrases or sentences must exist in a search
> document that have the language characteristics of an answer**, and
> the query itself must be posed as a question.